# How do I make my background-color fill entire width of div when applied to a `ul li`?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm using jQuery-UI-Layout plugin that creates a pane on the east side of the screen. When I create a list in it and apply a background-color to each `<li>` element, it doesn't span the width of the entire pane.

I would like it so that there is no white space on either side of the `<li>`, even if it has a bullet or number next to it (meaning if I decide to include a bullet or number, it should also be covered by the color). How can I do this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5EECD/497/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>

<div class="ui-layout-east">
    <ol id="someList">
        <li class="not-selected">step 1</li>
        <li class="selected">step 2</li>
        <li class="not-selected">step 3</li>
        <li class="not-selected">step 4</li>
    </ol>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.selected {
    background-color: #e90902;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.not-selected {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.ui-layout-pane-east {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Don't do this from the browser's inspector. jQuery UI's inner workings are supposed to calculate widths on page load.

Comment: hmm, I didn't know about the `!important` css property. I wonder what the usage policy around it is. Either way, that works, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/5EECD/502/

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing the

```
padding: 10px
```

from the following in css

```
body > div.ui-layout-east.ui-layout-pane.ui-layout-pane-east
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but when I do that (via using the browser's developer tools inspector) it shifts everything up and to the right. There is no space on the top or right side, but it still exists on the left.

Comment: Don't do this from the browser's inspector. jQuery UI's inner workings are supposed to calculate dimensions on page load!

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best way of doing it, though you can expand the margins of the `<li>` to fill the pane.

```
li{
    margin: 0px -10px 0px -10px;    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EECD/499/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your edited [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/5EECD/508/), with a List Style Disc "inside" the actual list item, by using the list-style-position style. To remove the Disc icon, simple use the style "none" instead.

If you set the  font-size to 0px and that will remove all white space from list items, as long as the list item has a given font size which is shown in the example.

I just added a little CSS to your working CSS:

```
ol#someList {
  font-size:0px;
  padding-left:0px;
  list-style:disc;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol#someList li {
  font-size:14px
}
```

I also added a body style to remove the default margin of 8px to show you that there is no white space to left or right of the list items.

Hope that helps!
Michael G

Comment: your "working fiddle" doesn't include the right jQuery-UI-Layout library so the divs aren't working properly. Can you put your code in my fiddle and then save it and edit the link? (that way it will have the right library) http://jsfiddle.net/5EECD/497/

Comment: I see, my fault. So, yes the padding !important like Narawa stated for the padding around the entire DIV is correct than. But the list itself, should probably be set like the above, with the disc type set inside.